# Display only the table/tag from HTML in WebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Is it possible to display only the particular tag from the webpage.
For example: https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf

I want to display only the login part to user. How to focus on that particular table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit ugly but how about injecting CSS into your WKWebView once the page is done loading? You are then free to style away any parts of the page you don't want to see. Assign a `WKNavigationDelegate` to your webview, and run some JavaScript injecting your styles when the page is done loading:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
  let script = """
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerHTML = "div#ad_unit { display: none; }";
  document.body.appendChild(style);
  """
  webView.evaluateJavaScript(script, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: How to hide? Can you please post example with any site or something which would help.

Comment: I updated my example with CSS hiding the big ad banner from your site.

Comment: Thanks it helped. I have one more problem. Is it possible the get the image from <img> tag?

Comment: Super, glad it helped you. I suggest you post a new question about the img tag.